# display one entry from column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that has two fields both id and value and I'd like to select which entry from the value column to display.

There are currently two entries and so far I've been able to echo both entries for the field together however ideally I only want to display one at a time and I'd like to choose which one.

```
function showTotal() {

     global $connection;
     $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

     if (!$result) {
         die('Query FAILED' . mysqli_error());
     } else if (isset($failed)) {
         echo "Failed";
     } 

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         $value = $row['value'];

         echo "$value";

     }
}
```

This displays a value of 110 for the two entries 1,10 whereas what I would like to echo is either 1 or 10.

Comment: To be able to choose which one you would have to specify the `id` during the query. `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id = 1;`

Comment: and how would you like to choose which one?

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestions. I went for the addition of an if statement if($row['id'] == 2){
    echo $value;
    }

Comment: You can do it in the code, but limiting the rows in the query is generally a better idea. MySQL is great at doing that sort of thing, and you avoid generating loads of data unnecessarily.